# Yew application unable to access static files when hosted in GitHub pages

Tags: github, github-pages, yew

I have [this](https://github.com/s1n7ax/my-website) website I'm planning to host in GitHub pages. The URL for the home page contains the name of the repository `https://s1n7ax.github.io/my-website/`. Static files linked in the HTML is trying to access them in `https://s1n7ax.github.io` base but the base should be `https://s1n7ax.github.io/my-website/`. How to configure this in a way that works both local and GitHub pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following adds the /my-website base to all the static file links.

```
trunk serve --public-url /my-website
```